# Converting Promise to different type even if result not yet available

Tags: java, promise, amazon-swf

I have the following activity:

```
@ActivityRegistrationOptions(defaultTaskScheduleToStartTimeoutSeconds = 300, defaultTaskStartToCloseTimeoutSeconds = 10)
@Activities(version="1.0")
public interface MyActivities {

    B first(A a) throws Exception;

    void second(C c) throws Exception;

}
```

And I have the following workflow:

```
public class MyWorkflowImpl implements MyWorkflow {

    @Autowired
    private MyActivitiesClient operations;

    @Override
    public void start(SomeType input) {
        A a = new A(...);

        Promise<B> b = operations.first(a);

        Promise<C> c = ...;
        /* Here, I would like to create c based on b */

        operations.second(c);
    }
}
```

Now `b` is not available until the first operation finishes, but the workflow continues even if `b` is not available.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Use @Asynchronous annotation of a method:

```
public void start(SomeType input) {
    A a = new A(...);

    Promise<B> b = operations.first(a);

    Promise<C> c = ...;

    operations.second(c);
}

@Asynchronous
private Promise<C> calculateC(Promise<B> b) {
    Settable<C> result = new Settable<C>();
           /* Here create c based on b */
    result.set(b.get()....);
    return result;
}
```

A method annotated as @Asynchronous is internally converted to a callback that is invoked when all its parameters of type Promise are ready. @Asynchronous implementation relies on AspecJ so make sure to follow setup instructions carefully to enable it.

Another option is to use Task:

```
@Override
public void start(SomeType input) {
    A a = new A(...);

    Promise<B> b = operations.first(a);

    Promise<C> c = new Settable<C>();
    new Task(b) {
        protected void doExecute() {
            /* Here c based on b */
            c.set(b.get() ....);
        }
    }
    operations.second(c);
}
```

Task doExecute method is invoked when all parameters of type Promise passed to Task constructor are ready.